# Banner doesn't work properly in multithread Android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, admob, banner

I've got a problem with making my banner work in my application. I've done a lot of search inside SO but couldn't find anything that helps me. The application is a video game that uses `Canvas` to draw the graphics. There is a while loop that calls `draw()` and `updateStateOfTheGame()` in a thread that runs continuously. To draw the banner I use the `WindowManager`. Here is the code of the activity where banner is displayed :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    private AdView adView;  
    private HomeMainGamePanel hMGP; // This class extends surfaceview and implements callback and does the drawing of canvas, bitmaps and other stuff in the game.
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "xxxxxxx";

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        hMGP=new HomeMainGamePanel(this, display,this);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        // window manager preparation 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        windowParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        windowParams.x = 0;
        windowParams.y = 0;
        windowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        windowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        windowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
          | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
        windowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        windowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

        WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
            .build();

        wm.addView(hMGP,windowParams);
        wm.addView(adView,windowParams);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        boolean retry = true;
        hMGP.getHomeMainThread().setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                hMGP.getHomeMainThread().join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            final WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
            wm.removeView(hMGP);
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

ok the fact is that if I remove `wm.addView(hMGP,windowParams);` from the code the ads works well. On the display we will see nothing but the banner, if you click it it will link you to the proper website. If I keep that line of code (wich is my task because that line is the line that displays the whole game graphics) when I click on the banner it doesn't work, or better it receives my click but cannot open the website, the logcat says `Could not get info for ads overlay`, here it is :

```
03-07 19:52:02.159: I/Ads(16984): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
03-07 19:52:02.159: I/Ads(16984): Ad finished loading.
03-07 19:52:02.189: I/chromium(16984): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-07 19:52:02.229: I/chromium(16984): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
03-07 19:52:02.229: E/qdutils(16984): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
03-07 19:52:08.325: D/HomeMainThread(16984): Game loop executed 658 times
03-07 19:52:10.468: W/Ads(17151): Could not get info for ad overlay.
```

I also have this in my proguard :

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.**

-keep public class com.google.gson.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}
```

Comment: Solved using join(500), don't know why but it all works now